# Alex, Dave or Jeff

Tags: cipher

A man has plotted to blow up a building. The police have three suspects. They have received a letter telling the name of the suspect. But it is coded, to avoid one of the other members of the suspect's criminal gang realising what has happened and changing the letter. This is what the letter says:

```
2-1, 5-3, 3-2, 9-2
```

Which suspect is guilty: Alex, Dave or Jeff?

(Sorry about the storyline, I have real trouble coming up with them)

Comment: I got a feeling it's Jeff, I just can't explain why.

Comment: @warspyking His name sounds more evil?

Comment: @warspyking - You need to decode the bit of pre-processed code to work it out. Also, unlike my last one, this one requires no special knowledge...

Comment: @mmking  Also see above.

Comment: Something to do with a keyboard?

Comment: @mmking I suppose it could be disputed over whether or not this is a keyboard. I know there is a more specific name for it, but I won't give too much away at the minute...

Comment: Well 3/9 are both divisible by 3 and they would represented "f", also note e is the 5th letter in the alphabet. I was all over the place but there was something hitting me about the pattern of numbers. Looks like I was seriously incorrect though.

Comment: @warspyking [Here's the next one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17091/a-member-of-my-family-is-killing-me)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it

> Alex

Because

> Telephone code
>  [image: telephone]
>  Hit 2 once to get A, hit 5 three times to get L, hit 3 twice to get E, hit 9 twice to get X

Answer (score 6):

I think it is:

> Jeff

My reasoning for this is because:

> If odd numbers represent consonants and even numbers represent vowels.
>  Computing the formulas gives us the numbers: 1,2,1,7. The only name that follows this order of Consonant, Vowel, Consonant, Consonant is JEFF!

Although looking at the

> phone code answer

that makes more sense.

Comment: I like this answer because it's creative and we all secretly doubt Jeff's innocence.

Comment: Well, it's probably not going to be Dave, since he's not going to fit the bill in any way.

Comment: Dave's a stand up guy.

Comment: Hmm, Mafia term. Maybe we should be wary after all.
[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stand+Up+Guy)