# Help! I'm dying!

Tags: riddle, cipher

You are woken up to hearing your neighbour shouting - "HELP! HELP! I'M DYING!"

You jump to your feet and run out into the street and see a man run away from your neighbours house, but he is too far away for you to catch up with him, and he is wearing a mask. You decide to investigate the house, as you are an ex-policeman. You use your spare keys to go inside the house and see the body on the floor, dead. You also see a bit of paper sticking out of his pocket. You pick it up. It reads:

> If you are reading this I am dead, but I believe I know who killed me. The answer is encrypted below.
>
> `eUXODGaaSDW8WURaLHaNWvjP2YNVJQWMSEdOWVQMSPdM9GaMJVjA6VQMJdRNWOhi7DcCATbiKRW`

Damn it. Your neighbour loved cryptography. Oh well, you may as well have a go, you suppose. Then you notice something else sticking out of his pocket. Another bit of paper:

> I've always had an extensive love of doughnut

What relation to him was the person that committed the murder?

NOTE: The reason of the puzzle being tagged "riddle" will be revealed later...

Hint 1:

> Only two words on the second bit of paper are important.

Hint 2:

> The two important words are "extensive" and "doughnut".

Hint 3:

> CodeNewbie has guessed (correctly) that it has something to do with a Vigenere Cipher. However, only one word is the Vigenere Cipher key. The other is something else...

Comment: Does "I've always had an extensive love of doughnut" refer to "XOR" operation ? Any other clues ?

Comment: @Prem "I've always had an extensive love of doughnut" is something else.

Comment: **DOUBT** : when the victim is active enough to shout an awkward sentence like "HELP! HELP! A MEMBER OF MY FAMILY IS KILLING ME!" , why did he not simply scream "HELP! HELP! My {Brother/Sister/Uncle/Aunt} IS KILLING ME!" ? Why he can not reveal the name of the killer in his screams ? **SUGGESTION** : I would probably change his screams to "HELP! HELP! I AM DYING!" , and the paper clues will mention that a "family member" is trying to kill him.

Comment: @Prem Good idea, I've edited.

Comment: Thought: Donuts could mean a circle or torus. It's odd that it's singular and not plural.

Comment: @EngineerToast , I guess Doughtnut refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doughnut in terms of cryptography.

Comment: @Prem That's a much better thought.

Comment: @EngineerToast It's not referring to a circle or a torus, but the fact that it is singular IS important...

Comment: @Prem It's not referring to that.

Comment: If he had enough time to write that message, then he must have known in advance that someone was going to kill him. In that time, couldn't he have called the police, gotten something to defend hinself, etc?

Comment: @mmking Yeah, there is always a few flaws with my storylines. I like to think that he asked for one last moment to write that letter, having good knowledge of cryptograms and stuffed it into his pocket as he was killed (the killer was lying, and killed him as soon as he turned to his desk to write the letter)!

Comment: @Kslkgh: Are the two words key to a vigenere cypher?

Comment: @CodeNewbie That is not a bad train of thought!

Comment: @CodeNewbie See the third hint for more...

Comment: But how can the numbers fit into a Vigenere cipher?

Comment: @randal'thor Think about the word 'extensive'. Thought of any words that are similar?

Comment: @Kslkgh Lengthy? Protracted? Wide-ranging? _Big_?

Comment: @randal'thor It's similar to a type of Vigenere Square...

Comment: Are you talking about "big doughnut" when you say "extensive" and "doughnut"?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Nope, doughnut is doughnut and extensive is similar to a type of Vigenere Square (see the above comments). Nice idea though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The murderer is

> The neighbour's son.

The message is encrypted using

> an Extended Vigenere Square, which includes the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and a space.

The decryption key, as mentioned by the hints, is

> doughnut

The decrypted text reads (punctuation added)

> Brothers and sisters I have none, but the murderer's father is my father's son.

This means that

> the murderer's father is the victim, and thus it is the victim's son or daughter that killed him.  Based on the clue about a masked man running from the house, I'm going to go with "son."  Hopefully he has only one, or the case could be tied up for a while in court...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Being given that words "extensive" and "doughnut" are important to solving this I collected every letter contained within those two words. This gave me this:

`eUXODGSDUHNvNVSEdOVSdGVVdNOhiDTi`

I'm not 100% sure, but I thing the killer's relation is **sister**, because from that string you can almost get an anagram sister. From the cipher text you can get `SisTE`. Because you also said the singular doughnut has a meaning I think this is it. You meant the last letter was missing for security from being able to determine anagram too fast.

Comment: Sorry, but no. There is a riddle involved.

Answer (score 0):

The murderer is

> one of his dad's other sons by a different mother.  The victim does not recognize him as a brother.  (Brothers and sisters I have none, but the murderer's father is my father's son.)

Reasoning:

> --------same father-------
>             |                                    |
> male murderer     male victim (no siblings)
> (apologies if the diagram above isn't formatted well on your screen)

Alternative:

> The fleeing masked man had nothing to do with the suicide.