# What is my mobile number

Tags: logical-deduction

10 years ago I met my old friend. He asked me for my mobile and number and I take his mobile and I wrote the following text:
**waemd.m ph**

Comment: To those editing:  Please check the edit history.  OP has specifically stated that the puzzle does not involve him taking down his friend's number.

Comment: [Similar](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16723/alex-dave-or-jeff).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mobile number is

> 92-3363160744

Using

> this mobile keypad
>  [image]
>  If I try to enter these letters I get the number
>  Here 92 is a country code

Comment: I...uh....guess we're assuming that `.` is obtained from the `1` key?

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Yeah..You are right.  I used my mom's cell phone to find the answer :p